# How do I get all the function names in the class? (Without extends)

Tags: php

I am trying to get all the function names in a class with PHP. Using the `get_class_methods()` method. But it writes in the function names of the class I extend. what I want is just the function names of the class I'm calling.

Example :

```
class a {
   public function index() {
      //...
   }
}

class b extends a {
   public function indexb() {
     //...
   }
}

print_r(get_class_methods(new b()));
```

Output :

```
array([0] => index, [1] => indexb);
```

(index) I do not want this area.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the methods for the child class, you're going to need to use [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php).

```
<?php

class A
{
    public function index() {}
}

class B extends A
{
    public function indexB() {}
}

$reflection = new ReflectionClass('B');

$methods = array_reduce($reflection->getMethods(), function($methods, $method) {
    if ($method->class == 'B') $methods[] = $method->name;

    return $methods;
}, []);

print_r($methods);
```

And a working example: https://3v4l.org/veTeQ

Comment: Nice! I was just about to post an almost identical answer - except using `array_filter` on the result.

Comment: @DarraghEnright, yeah I thought about `array_filter`, but you'd need to use `array_map` too, as `getMethods()` returns an array of objects. `array_reduce` allowed me to achieve the result in one loop.